# rails how hard is it to add a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, routes

This is my Error:

> Routing Error
>
> uninitialized constant OverviewController

Im new to rails I have NO idea what this means. I am trying to create a view based on the end of the URL being "overview", someone showed me I thought everything with an example "admin" and that works like a charm.

I have rails 1.9 installed (if that makes a difference).

I have my controller "overview_controller.rb" in the controllers directory. The source of it being.

```
class OverviewController < OverviewController
    def index
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
      end
    end
end
```

I have in my views directory overview/index.html.erb its source even simpler. "Overview Place Holder" thats it.

in my routes.rb I have
match "overview" => "overview#index"

this from my understanding is the same exact way the "admin" example I was given works. So why is it this isn't working for me with the "overview"

Comment: You have OverviewController inheriting from itself. You probably want OverviewController < ApplicationController

Comment: You probably have Ruby 1.9, not Rails 1.9.

Comment: its 1.9 whatever Im not sure. I inherited this project, I am a PHP developer switching to ruby/rails based on this need. This project was initially installed built up etc by someone else.

Comment: @DougR tried changing that line to match what you showed, and same issue. "uninitialized constant OverviewController"

Comment: try restarting your server as well

Comment: nope did not restart however after noticing this mention I tried, still got the same error.

Comment: What version of Rails? `rails -v` in console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to subclass the class by it's self, change the first line of your controller to this...

```
class OverviewController < ApplicationController
```

Comment: I tried this and still get the same issue "uninitialized constant OverviewController"

Comment: Silly question, but did you restart your server after making these changes?

Comment: nope did not restart however after noticing this mention I tried, still got the same error.

Comment: Maybe the issue isn't in this file, can we isolate the problem a little, maybe you have some more stack trace info you could post, maybe more of your project code?

Comment: Not really sure what to post. For what I am attempting to do, I have posted it all theres nothing more than that to that one view I am currently trying to do. And I basicly copy and pasted from another controller which was basicly a blank slate example there of which actually works. I get no other errors or options to show a trace with when I go to that particlar view either.